# Trouble using bootstrap_form gem - couldn't find file 'rails_bootstrap_forms' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to use the bootstrap_form ~> 2.0.1 gem (see https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) but it's giving me fits. I've installed is as per the instructions on their github page, adding it to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap_form', '~> 2.0.1'
```

I ran bundle install. I then added it to my application.css.scss file:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require_tree .
```

But, when I try to run my app I get:

> couldn't find file 'rails_bootstrap_forms' (in /path/to/my/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:12)

I'm obviously missing something. I checked lib/assets/ and vendor/assets/stylesheets/ but there's nothing there. Likewise, there's nothing in app/assets/stylesheets/.

What the fudge?

Answer (score 4):

I had some trouble with this, partly (I think) because they renamed the gem. What seemed to make the difference for me was to have bundle grab the latest gem from github, by putting this into my Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap_form', github: 'bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms'
```

I use bootstrap-sass, so I didn't want to mess around with application.css, so I made sure the following import statements were in application.css.scss, like this:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'rails_bootstrap_forms';
```

It's also quite important to remember to restart the server after making these changes!

Comment: Restarting server was a key. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have got to create the file rails_bootstrap_form.css in `app/assets/stylesheets`

```
.rails-bootstrap-forms-date-select,
.rails-bootstrap-forms-time-select,
.rails-bootstrap-forms-datetime-select {
  select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
  }
}
.rails-bootstrap-forms-error-summary {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and found that I'd mistyped the Gemfile entry as `bootstrap-form`. I corrected it to `bootstrap_form` and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Bootstrap? Looks like that is a requirement of bootstrap_form, but it's not included as a dependency in the gem which means you need to manually install Bootstrap.

One popular way to do this is with the [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails). The simplest way to install this is to include `gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"` in your gemfile, and then run

`$ bundle install`

followed by

`rails generate bootstrap:install static` which should add the required CSS files to your assets folder.

Comment: Hi Charles...yes, I had already added it above the bootstrap_form gem:
`gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'`
That's providing bootstrap to my app as it. Could that be incompatible with bootstrap_form, though?

Comment: Hmm interesting. What happens if you manually add [this file](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_bootstrap_forms.css) to your app/assets/stylesheets folder?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error so I took out `*= require rails_bootstrap_forms` from `application.css.scss` and was able to compile and deploy without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Despite SO's admonishment not to respond to other answers I'm going to enhance Thomas Geider's answer above by explaining why you need to create a rails_bootstrap_forms.css file in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

If you look in the rails-bootstrap-forms Github you'll notice they have a rails_bootstrap_forms.css file. The README doesn't tell you this but it follows that this css file needs to be in `/app/assets/stylesheets`.

Here's the file:

https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_bootstrap_forms.css